# Private and shared address book with LDAP?

Tags: ldap, openldap

For a set of users belonging to some organisation, I want to provide the following:

- each user should have a private address book
- each user should have access to a company address book

I wonder how to model this scenario in LDAP so that:

- user connects to LDAP server with some client
- user performs a search for some string
- all matching entries from the global address book are returned
- all matching entries from the user's private address book are returned

Is searching the global and private address book possible with a single query? I guess the user would provide his path in LDAP as DN, but the global address book would be located at a different DN. I imagine something like that:

```
/
/OU=private-address-books
      /CN=user1
               /CN=entry1
...
/OU=global-address-book
      /CN=entryABC
```

So is it possible to somehow automatically reference the global address book under the user's private address book?

Comment: PS: (not) It is always very helpful to get a negative vote without a comment :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably be best off to arrange your DIT Structure to be more like:
ou=private,ou=Addressbooks...
ou=public,ou=Addressbooks...
You then could search using the the ou=addressbooks as the baseDN.

Or better, assign an Attribute boolean type private=TRUE to each entry.
So for all addressbooks,

```
(objectClass=Entry)
```

And for private

```
(&(objectClass=Entry)(private=TRUE))
```

And then finally, you may be able to use an [ExtensibleMatch search filter](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/ExtensibleMatch#section-ExtensibleMatch-SearchWithinTwoContainers) to search both containers.

-jim

Comment: Yes, seems like I have to have some parent node, which I use to query. So the only option to keep private entities private is applying ACL to the different address books.